# Replace Youtube links in text with a specific embed code

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, youtube

Here's my problem.  I have a textarea in my form, where users can submit youtube video **links** .  I need to parse the text and replace the youtube link with their embed equivalents.  an example:

Initial URL in text:  "blah blah **http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLs5HN7FS0w** blah blah"
Final text before storing in mysql db: "blah blah **[youtube=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLs5HN7FS0w]** blah blah"

Any idea how to do this for every link in the textbox with **php**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got slightly bored, and came up with a ridiculously clunky, though relatively simple and functional, jQuery means of doing this:

```
$('form').submit(

function() {
    var text = $('#text').val().split(' ');
    for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var test = text[i].indexOf('http://www.youtube.com/watch');
        if (test != -1) {
            text[i] = '[youtube=' + text[i] + ']';
        }
    }
    text = text.join(' ').trim();
    $('#text').val(text);
    return false;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uLj9M/1/).

---

**Edited** to add a necessary sanity check to the function:

$('form').submit(

```
function() {
    var text = $('#text').val().split(' ');
    for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var test = text[i].indexOf('http://www.youtube.com/watch');
        var check = text[i].indexOf('[youtube=');
        if (test != -1 && check == -1) {
            text[i] = '[youtube=' + text[i] + ']';
        }
    }
    text = text.join(' ').trim();
    $('#text').val(text);
    return false;
});
```

[JS Fiddle of sanity-checking demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uLj9M/2/).

Basically, in the first function it was possible to simply keep re-submitting the form and prepending '[youtube=' and appending a closing ']'. This latter approach absolves me of some of the stupidity. OF course I could have just checked the the `indexOf()` value of 'test' is equal to 0, so it was at the beginning of the string. Which I might do, if I revisit this.

---

**Edited** because, sometimes, I just can't leave things be...

```
$('form').submit(

function() {
    var text = $('#text').val().split(' ');
    for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var test = text[i].indexOf('http://www.youtube.com/watch');
        if (test === 0) {
            text[i] = '[youtube=' + text[i] + ']';
        }
    }
    text = text.join(' ').trim();
    $('#text').val(text);
    return false;
});
```

[Updated JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uLj9M/3/).

---

**Edited** (again) because I can't leave things be, and because I figured (in the comments) that the jQuery example should be doable in php (more or less directly). And so here it is:

```
$text = $_POST['text']; // from the textarea of name="text"

$text = explode(" ",$text);
for ($i=0; $i < count($text); $i++) {
    if (stripos($text[$i], 'http://www.youtube.com/watch') === 0) {
        $text[$i] = '[youtube=' . $text[$i] . ']';
    }
}
$text = implode(" ",$text);
```

I don't know of anywhere that hosts `php` demos publically, and safely, so I can't demo this, but I think it *should* work. Although using a `foreach()` might well have been easier than a `for()` loop.

Comment: this is great, but if I use jquery, user can modify the embed code again, better off with php.  However, I'm storing this piece of code for later use, might come in handy :)

Comment: Well, possibly. And it's **always** necessary to validate the final submission from the user on the server-side before storage, or use...Anyway, glad to have helped! :)

Comment: Oh, @the_archer, it's worth noting (as an addenda) that the only reason I chose this method was my intense dislike/mistrust of regex (not to mention a certain degree of fear of the same). I can't think of any reason that this isn't directly transferable to php, all the basic methods are certainly available.

Comment: I certainly hate regex too. :P

Comment: @the_archer, a php, server-side, non-regex solution is posted! ...and now I think I'll leave this question alone, for a while... =D

Answer (score 3):

Use regular expressions:

```
$target = 'blah blah http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLs5HN7FS0w blah blah';
$target = preg_replace('/(http:\/\/www\.youtube[^ ]*)/', '[youtube=$1]', $target);
```

This matches everything that starts with `http://www.youtube` and does not contain spaces, and captures it into $1. Then it replaces the matched part with `[youtube=$1]` where $1 is the URL

Comment: does that work even if there are multiple links in the initial text?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a slightly more complex regExp, to be a bit safer and to drop all extra YT params that you don't really need (and users will paste them, you can bet on that):

```
$url = 'blabla http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6CyoYSlL-M&feature=rec-LGOUT-exp_stronger_r2-2r-26-HM aaaa bbb ccc';
echo preg_replace('|http://www\.youtube\.com/watch\?.*\bv=([^&]+)[^\s]*|', '[youtube=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1]', $url);
```

Also this BBcode shouldn't really require this "http://www.youtube..." part of the url, it's always the same ?!